# OpenServer MS SQL Php автоконвертация любой кодировки в ISO-8859-1 при записи в бд

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, кодировка, openserver

Есть 2 рабочих серва с одинаковыми БД MS SQL.

Через среду NB Php я запросом заношу данные(кирилица `UTF-8`) в БД на первый сервер - все нормально.

Заношу на воторой АНАЛОГИЧНО - в БД отображает не корректные символы

> ????N??µN????µN?-???°???°?·???? (a??2775)

в кодировке ISO-8859-1

ПРИЧЕМ в какой бы кодировке я не заносил прямо во время переноса конвертирует в ISO -8859-1

Что я только уже не пробовал: и типы полей менял, прописывал `collate`, 'N', `iconv`, `mb_convert_encoding` и даже задавал настройки соединения с БД:

```
mssql_query("SET character_set_client = '" . $codepage . "'",$link);
mssql_query("SET character_set_connection = '" . $codepage . "'",$link);
mssql_query("SET character_set_results = '" . $codepage . "'",$link);
mssql_query("SET NAMES '" . $codepage . "'",$link);
```

**ИТОГ** - один, только символы менялись на другую фигню,но до кирилицы никогда не доходило.

Латиницу передает нормально.

Пришел к выводу,что стоит на сервере какая-то автоконвертация при заносе в БД? Сам сервер трогать мне запрещают.

**Вопрос:** какой выход?

[Скрин](http://s017.radikal.ru/i412/1610/70/a337ad0f64ea.jpg)

Comment: Возможно, у баз установлен разный collation. Если права позволяют, то стоит попробовать задать его явно для проблемного столбца: `ALTER TABLE [table name] ALTER COLUMN [column name] COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS` (ну или `..._CS_AI`, или как там еще нужно по бизнес-логике).

Comment: у одной базы Cyrillic_General_BIN2 а у второй Cyrillic_General_BIN , но они же ничем не различаются для нашего случая. тем более явно задавать колейт я пробовал с самого начала + задавал разные типы ячейке nchar / nvarchar, но все равно не помогло

Comment: Хм... А если заносить данные INSERT'ом через SSMS, то будет та же история?

Comment: нет, если напрямую в базе писать запрос,то заносит нормально

Comment: Тогда стоит посмотреть профайлером, какие именно запросы Ваша среда отправляет на сервер.

Comment: вот как выглядят запросы,правда, я с этим 1 раз сталкиваюсь и не понимаю особо что тут что значит. может вы подскажете?
http://s017.radikal.ru/i415/1610/d1/3720d676d342.jpg

http://s48.radikal.ru/i122/1610/fe/66648e7d8afd.jpg

http://i042.radikal.ru/1610/e7/6d7be63d02e6.jpg

Comment: на 2-м скриншоте видно, что на сервер приходит текст уже в неверной кодировке. Соответственно, проблема не на стороне сервера, а на клиентской стороне, копать надо там. Но что зверь такой NB Php я, увы, представления не имею, так что ничего подсказать не смогу.

Answer (score -2):

Попробуй сделать, сравнение таблицы: utf8-general-ci[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И причем тут MySQL?